# Radiator turning off too soon

Tags: heating, radiator

We have recently had new radiators fitted, but one of them appears to be turning off too soon on the TRV.  Its a Myson TRV with numbers 1 - 4, as well as white and blue dots.

We have the TRV set to the blue dot, but it goes off even though the room is still cold. Is this normal?

Comment: is the blue dot the coldest setting? is the problem that cranked all the way up, it's still too cold? if so, it's possible the trv is not snug enough against the valve to fully depress the little springy thing (not a plumber).

Answer (score 2):

I had all sorts of trouble with TRV valves closing too soon or seeming never to open, no matter what temperature they were set at.

After spending most of a day bleeding and adjusting valves I could not solve the problem.

After thinking about it, I looked elsewhere in the system and it turned out to be that the boiler on my system had been set by the installer to 80 degrees, which is the max temperature.

This had the effect that the water flowing through the valve was so hot that the pipes heated some of the valves to the point that they shut down.

The boiler is now set to around 65 degrees and everything is working like it should.

Answer (score 0):

No you have a problem with the TRV.  Somehow the wiring is mixed up.  the room heater should stay warm until the room is comfortable. Maybe the TRV for that room is not connected properly. P.

Comment: The only "TRV" devices I've seen are purely mechanical devices - no wiring involved.